# What is the name of this rose?

Tags: roses

[image]This rose is blooming in my garden. Purchased this place six months ago, and it has lots of roses. This one has me stumped. Long stems without a lot of thorns. Dark pink and light pink stripes.

Comment: Please add Picture of your plant

Comment: I thought it was uploaded. Now I can’t find an up load or copy location. Help. New to site.

Comment: go to edit and you can add again a picture in it.